# Правильная генерация уникального ID (int)

Tags: php, mysql

для генерации уникальной ссылки на пост, с последующим хранением ее в базе, использую следующий алгоритм:

```
function generate(){
    $secretKey = "dfslkFDe#R%";
    $testKey = sha1($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) . $secretKey . (time() * rand());

    $result = sha1($testKey);

    return preg_replace("/[^\d]/", "", $result);
}
```

потом от результата, я в случайном порядке выбираю 5 цифр. Скажите, будут ли здесь коллизии?

P.S. нужны именно цифры

Comment: чем вас не устаривает автоинкремент, чем вас не устраивает математическое преобразование автоинкремента?

Comment: как осуществляется математическое преобразование автоинкремента?

Comment: да хоть (9999 + id) или, наоборот, (100000 - id), или еще какая-то игра, которая сделает из первых 89999 идентификаторов уникальные числа от 10000 до 99999.